# SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value, html_entity_decode function

Tags: php, html, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have been trying html_entity_decode as below;

```
//Foreach ($datas from remote db)
$recorded = User::updateOrCreate([
        "old_id" => $user->Id,
        "username" => $user->UserName,
    ],[
        "old_id" => $user->Id,
        "name" => html_entity_decode($user->FullName),
        "username" => $user->UserName
]
```

and it gives me an error like as follow,

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE3\xBCseyi...' for
column `database`.`users`.`name` at row 1 (SQL: update `users` set
`name` = hseyin furkan, `users`.`updated_at` = 2021-02-22 18:23:39 where `id` = 2)
```

If i dont call **html_entity_decode** function, it writes to column like "h&#252;seyin"

How can i fix it?

My table:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('username')->nullable();
```

Comment: please share your input string

Comment: but maybe your `name` column type is datetime, you need to change to varchar

Comment: no, my name column string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably, your data is ASCII character set, and your column waits for UTF-8
Can you try this code;

```
mb_convert_encoding(html_entity_decode($user->FullName), "UTF-8")
```

If you use laravel, you can use the function that;

```
$fullname = Str::ascii(html_entity_decode($user->FullName),'tr');
```